# One build definition won't generate fakes assemblies, another one does

Tags: tfs, msbuild, microsoft-fakes

## Introduction

I have a problem with Team Foundation Server Express 2013 on my machine. I have two build definitions on the same controller and agent, both of which run on the same server and the same environment as well.

**It should be noted that I already looked at the "similar questions" without any luck. This is clearly not related to the same root cause, and the symptoms are slightly different too.**

One of them is a gated check-in build definition, which just compiles everything when commiting to the development branch.

Another is a scheduled build definition, which runs every saturday at 3 AM, building any changes that may have been committed to the main branch since last time.

The gated build definition has a process (which only has minor changes for not running tests and just compiling the code) based on the `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` template.

The scheduled build definition process is based on some Azure build definition template that might come from an older version of Visual Studio, possibly based on some Azure template, or maybe the `TfvcContinuousDeployment.12.xaml` template.

## The issue

My gated build definition runs just as expected, without issues. It compiles the full solution, and only passes if the compilation succeeds.

The shceduled build definition however fails *compiling* (even before it reaches the point where it runs the unit tests). The error I see is as follows.

[image: Fakes generation build error]

Obviously this is due to missing fakes assemblies. I tried taking the assemblies and checking them in (which I would rather avoid), only to find that this build definition runs just fine, but not the gated one which ran just fine before.

I thought about just running `fakes.exe` in the build template to just generate them manually before compiling, but in my initial tests (to see if this theory would even work), it won't even run in the commandline, and outputs some errors and warnings that I don't understand (but are probably not relevant anyway, since I might be running `fakes.exe` with improper arguments).

## Updates

### Update #1

It should be noted that I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed on my build server as well. Both this (and TFS 2013 Express) have Update 3 installed, and the server is fully updated.

Comment: Does the scheduled build use the same user and privileges? Is 'Fakes' properly managed e.g. with nuget, so that it is accessible in all configurations? Does a clean (new) check out work out of the box?

Comment: The gated definition does not explicitly restore NuGet packages, but the scheduled definition runs `nuget restore` on projects before compiling them. But what does NuGet have to do with Fakes?

Comment: Can you check the workspace mapping between the 2 builds to make sure the fakes reference isn't being brought in from somewhere else in the working version.

Comment: Nuget would place libraries in ..\packages\.. where without nuget, the references could point to files accessible for one build user, but not for the other.

Comment: Oh, well the thing is that I didn't check in the binaries for the fakes. They should be generated automatically by the build server, right? And they are indeed generated properly on the gated checkin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up abandoning fakes all together, and implementing Moq instead. Works a lot better, and forces me to abandon shims or moles, which are often considered bad practise anyway.